# Bootstrap is blocking of the display of inline svg

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, svg, bootstrap-4

I see `<svg>` is working in html file and i moved in an asp.net project. Firstly, it was ok. But after adding `bootstrap.min.css` svg dissapers on the page.

How can i use `<svg>` tags with Bootstrap 4?

**SVG Code:**

```
<svg version="1.1" class="mysvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path d="M504.502,75.496c-9.997-9.998-26.205-9.998-36.204,0L161.594,382.203L43.702,264.311c-9.997-9.998-26.205-9.997-36.204,0    c-9.998,9.997-9.998,26.205,0,36.203l135.994,135.992c9.994,9.997,26.214,9.99,36.204,0L504.502,111.7    C514.5,101.703,514.499,85.494,504.502,75.496z"></path>
     </g>
    </g>
 </svg>
```

**Note:** You can see in the HTML code of svg via F12 Developer View but you can not see on the page.

Comment: bootstrap does not remove SVGs it must be something else.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the path in two groups? Groups for svg is only necessary when combining multiple svg elements to create one vector image.

Comment: I just found the html of svg code and moved in an asp.net project. It was working well until i imported bootstrap.min.css or i have tried bootstrap.css. After that i can see in html it is still there but i can not see on the page. Item disappers.

Comment: And i have tried different svg codes too. All of them being invisible.

Comment: Any updates, since I am having this issue too?